# Separate strings into groups of 2 characters separated by colon (1330 to 13:30) in R

Tags: regex, r

How do I turn `"1330"` into `"13:30"`, or `"133000"` into `"13:30:00"`?  Essentially, I want to insert a colon between every pair of numbers. I'm trying to convert characters into times.

It seems like there should be a really elegant way to do this, but I can't think of it. I was thinking of using some combination of `paste()` and `substr()`, but an elegant solution is escaping me.

EDIT: example string that needs to be converted:

```
X <-   c("120000", "120500", "121000", "121500", "122000", "122500", "123000") #example of noon to 12:30pm
```

Comment: Can you provide reproducible code to create the data you are looking at?

Comment: as.POSIXct will do what you wish, using the correct format.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This replaces each sequence of two characters not followed by a boundary with those same characters followed by a colon:

```
gsub("(..)\\B", "\\1:", X)
```

On the sample string it gives:

```
[1] "12:00:00" "12:05:00" "12:10:00" "12:15:00" "12:20:00" "12:25:00" "12:30:00"
```

Comment: Wow, this is also a very nice answer.  I'm learning a lot about `regex()` from the answer I'm getting to this question.  I just spent about 10 minutes reading through ?regex, and decided I can't tell which answer is more robust, this, or the one posted by @flodel (I'm still not very familiar with regular expressions that well). It seems both answer are great.

Comment: Nice, I didn't know that `b` referred to boundaries!

Answer (score 8):

You can use a regular expression with a [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
gsub("(\\d{2})(?=\\d{2})", "\\1:", X, perl = TRUE)
# [1] "12:00:00" "12:05:00" "12:10:00" "12:15:00" "12:20:00" "12:25:00" "12:30:00"
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `substring`:

```
test <- "1330"
paste(substring(test,seq(1,nchar(test)-1,2),seq(2,nchar(test),2)),collapse=":")

#[1] "13:30"


test <- "133000"
paste(substring(test,seq(1,nchar(test)-1,2),seq(2,nchar(test),2)),collapse=":")

#[1] "13:30:00"
```

Or if you want an actual time representation you could do:

```
test <- "1330"
as.POSIXct(test,format="%H%M")
#[1] "2013-05-09 13:30:00 EST"
```

Which you can reformat like:

```
format(as.POSIXct(test,format="%H%M"),"%H:%M")
#[1] "13:30"
```

Comment: +1 for homing in on the practical application and suggesting POSIXct, but the gsub() suggestion is a more general solution.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Can do it with strptime in one step:

```
strptime(X, format="%H%M%S")
[1] "2013-05-08 12:00:00" "2013-05-08 12:05:00" "2013-05-08 12:10:00" "2013-05-08 12:15:00" "2013-05-08 12:20:00"
[6] "2013-05-08 12:25:00" "2013-05-08 12:30:00"
```

After the complaint about the dates in date-time objects, one can suppress that "artificial" reality with:

```
strftime( strptime(X, format="%H%M%S"), "%H:%M:%S" )
[1] "12:00:00" "12:05:00" "12:10:00" "12:15:00" "12:20:00" "12:25:00" "12:30:00"
```

Comment: That adds an artificial month+day component to the output.